# What is the difference between arr and *arr?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is the difference between these 2 prints, I got the same address in both of them :

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    printf("%p\n", arr);
    printf("%p\n", *(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is an array of 2 arrays of a 3 `int`. Consider these three things:

- The array `arr`.
- The first subarray of `arr`, also called `arr[0]`.
- The first element of `arr[0]`, also called `arr[0][0]`.

These three things start in the same place. The first subarray in `arr` is at the beginning of `arr`, so it starts where `arr` starts. And the first element of `arr[0]` is at the beginning of `arr[0]`, and it is at the beginning of `arr`. Since the three things all start in the same place, it is not surprising that they appear to thace the same address.

Now, let’s look at what you printed. First, when printing a pointer, you ought to convert it to `void *`, as in `printf("%p\n", (void *) arr);`.

That said, `printf(… arr)` prints the address of `arr[0]`. Why `arr[0]` and not `arr`? Because, when used in an expression like this, an array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So `arr` is automatically converted to a pointer to `arr[0]`, and this is what the `printf` prints.

Similarly, `printf(… *(arr))` prints the address of `arr[0][0]`. This is because, as above, `arr` is converted to a pointer to `arr[0]`. Then, since it is a pointer to `arr[0]`, `*(arr)` applies `*` to that pointer, and the result is `arr[0]`. Since `arr[0]` is an array, it is also converted to a pointer to its first element. So the result is a pointer to `arr[0][0]` and that is what `printf` prints.

So, you are printing the address of `arr[0]` and the address of `arr[0][0]`. Since they start in the same place, it is not surprising the address is the same.

(It is not actually required that printing the addresses would produce the same string. The C standard allows an implementation to represent addresses in multiple ways. So it is possible that printing two different pointers to the same address could result in different output. That is fairly rare in modern C implementations.)

Answer (score 2):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

Given the declaration

```
int arr[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

the memory layout will be

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0][0]
   +---+ 
   | 2 | a[0][1]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[0][2]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[1][0]
   +---+
   | 5 | a[1][1]
   +---+
   | 6 | a[1][2]
   +---+
```

So, one thing to notice - the address of `a` will be the same as the address of `a[0]`, which will be the same as the address of `a[0][0]`.  The address of `a[1]` will be the same as the address of `a[1][0]`.

The *expression* `a` has type "2-element array of 3-element array of `int`", so unless it's the operand of `&` or `sizeof`, the type of the expression will "decay" to "pointer to 3-element array of `int` (`int (*)[3]`), and its value will be the address of the first element of `a` (`&a[0]`).

The expression `*a` has type "3-element array of `int`", so unless it is the operand of `&` or `sizeof`, the type of the expression will "decay" to "pointer to `int`, and the value of expression will be the address of the first element of `*a` (`&(*a)[0]`, which is equivalent to `&a[0][0]`).

As mentioned above, the address of `a` is the same as the address of `a[0]`, which is the same as the address of `a[0][0]`.  In fact, *all* of the following expressions evaluate to the same address: `&a`, `a`, `*a`, `a[0]`, `&a[0]`, `&a[0][0]`, although the *types* of the expressions are different.  See the following table:

```
Expression        Type          "Decays" to        Value
----------        ----          -----------        -----
         a        int [2][3]    int (*)[3]         Address of a[0]
        *a        int [3]       int *              Value of a[0]
        &a        int (*)[2][3] n/a                Address of a
      a[i]        int [3]       int *              Value of a[i]
     *a[i]        int           n/a                Value of a[i][0]
     &a[i]        int *         n/a                Address of a[i]
   a[i][j]        int           n/a                Value of a[i][j]
  &a[i][j]        int *         n/a                Address of a[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

arr without indices is basically a pointer to the zeroeth element of the array, in context of your question there is no difference

```
arr <==> *arr
```

that is the reason you are getting the same address, In the next stage lets, we want to access the array elements then one method is trivial `arr[i][j]` or you can implement it like this in using pointer `*(*(arr + i) + j)`, now the implementation may seem more different from each other but they are both accessing the same address just like in your case, so in this example also there address will be same, and same for all such cases.